# How to tell VScode, on my Mac running high Sierra, which version of python to use

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I use VScode to write and run python. I use it with a Jupyter extension. I have 2 virtual environments created using Anaconda.  One py27, for python 2.7.13 and the other, py36, for Python 3.6.5.

I have a simple code which I edited to only run in python2.  When I run VScode, the virtual environment I run it in does not seem to matter. VScode seems to run but I can't figure out how to make it use py36 (python 3.6.5) or py27 (python 2.7.13).

By using different commands in the command palette, or double-clicking on phrases in the bottom border of VScode I can eventually get it to run which version I want. But I have not found a reproducible method.

I have tried about 100 times with no luck. I thought I found a method that would repeat but I tried it again and it didn't work.

I know this question is very vague but it would take pages to explain what I've tried. I have about 5 or 6 settings which I've tried a plethora of combinations. One of the commands I tried is to select a python interpreter. I have several options but none seem to have an effect. Also, in the bottom border of the VScode window, there is the name of a specific python interpreter. You can click on this to select a different python interpreter. As far as I can tell this doesn't do anything. Actually, it's a hindrance because a user may think they are actually using that interpreter.

I've tried both py27 and p36 but I get no difference. If I can get visual studio code to start out in py27, I can make it change to py36 and back to py27. But how to make it start in py27 seems random. My virtual environments are in my home directory, /User/myname/py27 for example along with the VScode app.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments explains how to select your virtual environment. Without knowing where you installed the virtual environments the best I can tell you is you can manually specify what interpreter to use with the `python.pythonPath` setting or if you have both virtual environments in a directory outside of your workspace folder you can specify the common folder with the `python.venvPath` setting.

Comment: Thanks for reply!  The virtual environments, py27 and py36 are in my home folder which is /Users/myname/  The VScode folder is in my home folder.

Comment: I put the virtual environment locations in a comment. I also read the reference you listed but I've had no success in controlling the virtual environment initially used by VScode. Any further help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There should be two ways to solve this. Assuming you're on Linux, setting `"python.pythonPath": "/home/jmh/py36/bin/python"` should work. You should also be able to do `"python.venvPath": "/home/jmh/"` and then have them both be listed when you run the `Select Interpreter` command.

Comment: Well I'm running on a Mac but I'm using it from the command line which is Unix.

Comment: Do you mean set python.venvPath:/home/jmh/  ? In the settings file?

Comment: I have the following set:"python.pythonPath": "/Usersjmh/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python",
    "python.venvPath": "/Users/jmh"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't piece together that when you said "virtual environments" you meant "conda environments". [Conda environments are special](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments), so make sure you specified a Python version when creating them, otherwise the extension won't pick them up.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did. py27 was created with python 2.7.15 and py36 was assigned to python 3.6.5. They seem to work because if I activate py27 and then run python from the command line, the python version 2.7.15 is used.  Likewise for py36.

Comment: Then they should be showing up as options in the selector. If you're running the latest VS Code and version of the extension this may be a bug, in which case open one at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python