# How do I get VS Code to recognize modules in virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I set up a virtual environment in python 3.7.2 using "python -m venv foldername". I installed PIL in that folder. Importing PIL works from the terminal, but when I try to import it in VS code, I get an ImportError. Does anyone know how to get VS code to recognize that module?

I've tried switching interpreters, but the problem persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell VScode, on my Mac running high Sierra, which version of python to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456360/how-to-tell-vscode-on-my-mac-running-high-sierra-which-version-of-python-to-us)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvisual-studio-code%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+how+to+use

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the python.venvpath setting to a different folder, and then moving the virtual env folder(The one with my project in it) to that folder. After restarting VS code, it worked.